# Auth0 Authorization Stops Working When API is Published (.Net Web API / Angular)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, api, windows-server-2012-r2, auth0

I am currently using Auth0 with Loc7 in Angular and an ASP .Net Web API v2.

The project works fine locally. The user can log in using the widget and the API sees the User as authorised with no issue.

When the app is published the API returns 401 unauthorised when a call is made.

There is no issue with Angular app no matter where on the web space it is placed so I do not believe it is an issue with the Allowed Callback URLs in the Auth0 dashboard.

The config works fine locally and there are no major changes when being published except the database connection string.

The database is an exact copy of the local database.

The API MVC Template works fine but does not do anything aside from load and show routes. I have not changed the template since it was generated.

There are no errors on the server.

The API is in a newly created app directory on the server.

Auth0 Dash reports the login from the Angular code successful.  The profile is returned with a valid token viewed through the dev console.

Has anyone else had a similar issue?  Could this be an issue with how the hosting is set up?

Happy to post more info, I am not really sure what to post it is a fair amount of code.

Comment: A few things that might help troubleshoot: **1.** Include the `WWW-Authenticate` header returned with the 401 response. **2.** Specify (include code if possible) how do you validate the token in the Web API.

Comment: The header was exactly what it was.  I had to add:
 
Authorize: 'bearer' + token.


On my local machine it was not needed I had the following instead:

xhrFields: {
                     withCredentials: true
                 }

It kept me up most the night and as usual it was something very simple that I overlooked. 

If you would like I can post the code this afternoon and you can write the answer.  Your comment was the correct answer.

Comment: Glad you got this sorted while trying to get troubleshooting information. In these cases where you end up solving the original problem you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. (It's completely okay to accept your own answer.) This way people with similar issues will have an easier time finding the solution

Comment: Good to know. I ran into another issue I think is header related, once I get that sorted I will post my answer.